# SetInterval times not running correctly

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've inherited a bug to look at consisting of two images that "flip" and use set interval to time when this happens.

From what I believe the initial change should happen after 4 seconds, then for each image change every 12 seconds (obviously this isn't important at the minute).

At the moment the first image changes at 4 seconds and the second one at around 8.

I'm also open to any improvements that can be made to this code as well.

```
//SPINNING LOGO
        if ($("#flipLogo").length) {
            function spinLogo() {
                $('#flipLogo').addClass("active");
                $('#flipLogo2').addClass("active");
//                console.log("yup yup");
                setTimeout(function () {
                   $('#flipLogo').removeClass("active");
                   $('#flipLogo2').removeClass("active");
                }, 4000);
                clearInterval();
            }
            setInterval(function () {
                spinLogo();
                clearInterval();
            }, 12000);
        }
```

Comment: `clearInterval` take the intervalId as argument retrieved by `setInterval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [$.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to switch between the active states.
Additionally, as Hacketo said you are calling `clearInterval` wrong - it should be called with the return value of setInterval if you want to **stop** the interval (I don't think you want to do this?)
Try this:

```js
//SPINNING LOGO
function spinLogo() {
    // Flip the active classes on or off
    $('#flipLogo').toggleClass("active");
    $('#flipLogo2').toggleClass("active");
}
if ($("#flipLogo").length) {
    // after 4 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        // flip the logo
        spinLogo();
        // Set a timer to flip it again every 12 seconds
        setInterval(spinLogo, 12000);
    }, 4000);
}
```

Here it is in action:

```js
//SPINNING LOGO
function spinLogo() {
  // Flip the active classes on or off
  $('#flipLogo').toggleClass("active");
  $('#flipLogo2').toggleClass("active");
}
if ($("#flipLogo").length) {
  // after 4 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    // flip the logo
    spinLogo();
    // Set a timer to flip it again every 12 seconds
    setInterval(spinLogo, 12000);
  }, 4000);
}
```

```css
.flippable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
.flippable.active {
  display: block;
}

#flipLogo {
  background: blue;
}
#flipLogo2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flipLogo" class="flippable active">Logo 1</div>
<div id="flipLogo2" class="flippable">Logo 2</div>
```

(ps it is bad form to define functions inside if statements, as [hoisting will move them them to a place you might not expect](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html))

Comment: Hi, like I said I've inherited this code and I'm not a huge javascript developer. I'll give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: So called "hoisting" doesn't move function declarations. They are processed before any code is executed, so they can be called in lines above the declaration. The term "hoisting" is quite misleading.

Comment: @RobG If you see the second example in the link, the variable that contains the function for first-class shenanigans *is* hoisted though. Either way, don't function in psuedo-sub-scopes.